# What is a good book to learn JavaScript for complete beginners?

Tags: javascript, web-development, books

I could not find a good book for learning JavaScript. I Googled but most books seem to assume that you have some programming experience and don’t teach from the ground up. They assume you should know how this does this and how to make certain things happen right off the bat. I have no programming experience except know how to write in HTML and CSS. I would like to practice alongside the book and be able to build projects (alongside book too) and reach an intermediate level of proficiency. Could you please point me to some books for absolute beginners learning JavaScript? Please note that the book should follow the latest ECMAScript standard since they keep on adding and removing features. Thank you!

Comment: wonder if you read what [tag:books] tag says, "Do not ask for book recommendations, they are off-topic for this site!" This is not a better fit here than it was [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362432/what-is-a-good-in-depth-book-for-absolute-beginner-in-javascript), sorry. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: Where can I get the recommendations then?

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one for BOOKS https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat

Answer (score -1):

Book from beginner to a professional javascript book. I would say stay away from javascript books that jump straight to web  development. Look for book that teaches you in depth into the language. This is one of my recommendation

Javascript: The definitive guide